# Conv2d Destructor crash Pytorch C++ API

Tags: c++, pytorch

[image]I have the following code, the code runs and result correct but it crashes on the destructor of
Conv2d, any on encountered such thing ?

```
    torch::Tensor kernel = torch::full({ 1, 32, 1, 2 }, 0, torch::kInt32);
    // Define the bias
    torch::Tensor bias = torch::tensor({ 0 }, torch::kInt32);
    // Define the input image
    torch::Tensor image = torch::full({ 32, 6, 7 }, 0, torch::kInt32);

    /// Define the convolution operation
    //depth_conv = Conv2d(in_channels = 10, out_channels = 10, kernel_size = 3, groups = 10)
    torch::nn::Conv2d depth_conv = torch::nn::Conv2d(
        torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(32, 1, {1,2}).groups(1).bias(false)
    );
     
    // Set the filter for the con[![enter image description here][1]][1]volution operation
    depth_conv->weight = kernel;

    // Set the bias for the convolution operation
    depth_conv->bias = bias;
    std::cout << "Original Data Tensor:\n" << image << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Original Wght Tensor:\n" << depth_conv->weight << std::endl;
    

    // Apply the convolution operation

    torch::Tensor output = depth_conv->forward(image);
    std::cout << "Output:\n" << output.dtype() << std::endl;

    // Print the output shape and values
    std::cout << "Output Shape: " << output.sizes() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Output:\n" << output.dtype() << std::endl;
```

Comment: What's the exact error? - this is only the stack trace you are showing. Also I assume you are showing the code of the cnnDepthwiseTask method in this trace. What if you instead of `torch::nn::Conv2d depth_conv` you do `auto depth_conv` (assuming you are using C++>11, and also assuming this is the destructor that is causing the issue).

Comment: And also I assume a lot of other things - just show more information - for one also include where does your snippet starts in your real project (line number).